# TYPO3 RTE p tags missing in frontend

Tags: typo3, fluid, rte, typo3-7.6.x

In the backend I enter text in a textarea. The code view shows the p tags. The p tags are missing in the database field (as it should be by default).

However, when I try to output the field in fluid like this, it's missing the p tags:

```
<f:format.html>{bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

Am I missing a RTE TypoScript setting?

I'm on TYPO3 7.6 with `fluid_styled_content`.

Comment: Do you have css_styled_content or fluid_styled_contend included in template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your Typoscript settings or extension settings if you have something similar to this:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 31]
  tt_content.stdWrap.dataWrap >
  lib.parseFunc_RTE.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >
[global]
```

Which basically unsets the tt.content data wrapping and Rte wrapping.